# MailChimp API member-info issue

Tags: php, mailchimp

I need to retrieve all users infos via api, looking for it in the documentation I found this:
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php

This is my code:

```
$params = array(
            'id' => $list_id,
            'emails' => array(
                            'euid' => $member_id,
                        ),
        );
        $infos = $this->MailChimp->call('lists/member-info', $params);

print_r($infos);
```

and this is the result:

```
Array ( [success_count] => 0 [error_count] => 1 [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => 63a885b7cf [error] => "email" should be a struct [code] => -100 ) ) [data] => Array ( ) )
```

What does " "email" should be a struct " means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved!
My `$params` array was wrong.

MailChimp need an array format in this way:

```
$params = array(
            'id' => $list_id,
            'emails' => array(
                          0 => array(
                              'euid' => $member_id,
                          ),
                        ),
        );
```

Answer (score 11):

This also works and is slightly simpler:

```
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/member-info', array(
            'id'        => $list_id,
            'emails'    => array(array('email'=>$email))
          ));
```

The above example uses this API: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/

Answer (score 3):

Mine does this as follows:

```
array(
  '0' => array('email' => $mail1)
  '1' => array('email' => $mail2)
  ...
  ...
);
```

Thanks,