# Mailchimp API: Add subscribers to segments

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm making a script to add subscribers to mailchimp list and assigns them to a segment. Adding subscribers to lists works fine, but when I try to assign to a segment, mailchimp api returns an error.

This is the code

```
    <?php
$api_key = "MYAPYKEY";
$list_id = "MYLIST";
$segment_id = "SEGMENT_D";

$merge_vars = Array( 
        'FNAME' => 'James', 
    );

require('src/Mailchimp.php');
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => 'example@example.com' ),$merge_vars,'','false','true');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($subscriber);
echo '</pre>';

$segment = $Mailchimp_Lists->staticSegmentMembersAdd($list_id, $segment_id, array("email" => "example@example.com"));

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($segment);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

And here result

```
array(3) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(16) "my@email.com"
  ["euid"]=>
  string(10) "cdb3aa63cb"
  ["leid"]=>
  string(9) "132001013"
}
array(3) {
  ["success_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "my@email.com"
      ["code"]=>
      int(232)
      ["error"]=>
      string(59) "There is no record of the email address "m" in your account"
    }
  }
}
```

First var_dump it's ok result when add email to list, and second var_dump it's error when adding it to segment.

The Segment exists. I see that API only takes first letter of email.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$segment = $Mailchimp_Lists->staticSegmentMembersAdd($list_id, $segment_id, array(array("email" => "example@example.com")));
```

Need to nest the email array
Found this out from this page [MailChimp API member-info issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956733/mailchimp-api-member-info-issue)

Worked for me when I had exactly the same problem as you.